# Display name of near by places of current location using google map api

Tags: jquery, asp.net, google-maps

I am making a web application in which user can search parking spaces.when user clicks on a particular parking space its map is appeared. I also want to find the places nearby that location and display their address/name on my web page.
How can i do this using jquery in asp.net.

[image]

Comment: Are you required to use Google Maps for retrieving nearby places? Or could you use something like the Foursquare API?

Comment: i want to retrieve it by using google map api